# How do I expand the clickable area of a WinForms ListView item?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I'm using a ListView control in a WinForms app, and I notice that I have to be very precise with my clicking to select an item - if I don't click on the text or the icon, nothing gets selected! Is there any way to expand the clickable area so I can click near the text or icon (for instance, to the right of an item with a short text string) and actually select something? Or do I have to use a ListBox, TreeView, or GridView control to do that? I like the grouping capability of the ListView, but this issue is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is a Win32 control under the hood, which prohibits such customizations.

You may try [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), which is free and is fully managed. It supports advanced Hit Test so that you can detect clicking on item space and update selection accordingly. It also allows expanding the text area (this is however possible only in the [full version](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview)).

[enter link description here](http://www.componentowl.com/documentation/better-listview/data/chapter-hit-test.html)

Answer (score -1):

`ListView.FullRowSelect = true;`